# Flink batch job always fail due to AskTimeoutException or Heartbeat of TaskManager with id container timed out

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-flink

I run a flink batch job on YARN. The job reading data from multiple HDFS path and union them to one data set, and based on this data set, calculate the groupBy and reduce function. But the job can not finish successfully.

Hadoop YARN verion: 2.6.0
Flink version: 1.9.1

submit yarn session shell:

```
./bin/yarn-session.sh -jm 20480 -tm 51200 -s 1 -nm 'Batch Job' \
    -Djobmanager.rpc.port=6123 \
    -Djobmanager.web.address=0.0.0.0 \
    -Drest.port=8081 \
    -Dtaskmanager.network.memory.fraction=0.2 \
    -Dparallelism.default=6 \
    -Dhigh-availability=zookeeper \
    -Dhigh-availability.zookeeper.quorum=hadoop-infra-1.com:2181,hadoop-infra-2.com:2181,hadoop-infra-0.com:2181 \
    -Dhigh-availability.zookeeper.path.root=/flink-1.9.1-yarn \
    -Dhigh-availability.storageDir=hdfs://hadoop-infra-0.com:8020/flink/flink-1.9.1/ha/ \
    -Dstate.backend=rocksdb \
    -Dstate.backend.incremental=true \
    -Dstate.checkpoints.dir=hdfs://hadoop-infra-0.com:8020/flink/flink-1.9.1/flink-checkpoints \
    -Dstate.savepoints.dir=hdfs://hadoop-infra-0.com:8020/flink/flink-1.9.1/flink-savepoints \
    -Djobmanager.web.submit.enable=true \
    -Djobmanager.archive.fs.dir=hdfs://hadoop-infra-0.com:8020/flink/flink-1.9.1/completed-jobs/ \
    -Dhistoryserver.archive.fs.dir=hdfs://hadoop-infra-0.com:8020/flink/flink-1.9.1/completed-jobs/ \
    -Dhistoryserver.archive.fs.refresh-interval=20000 \
    -Dyarn.application-attempts=1000 \
    -Dfs.hdfs.hadoopconf=/etc/hadoop/conf \
    -Dakka.lookup.timeout='100 s' \
    -Dakka.ask.timeout='1000 s' \
    -Dweb.timeout=10000 \
    -Dtaskmanager.registration.timeout='10 min' \
    -Dmetrics.reporters=flink_jmx_reporter,flink_prometheus_ops_reporter \
    -Dmetrics.scope.delimiter=: \
    -Dmetrics.reporter.flink_jmx_reporter.class=org.apache.flink.metrics.jmx.JMXReporter \
    -Dmetrics.reporter.flink_jmx_reporter.port=9020-9040 \
    -Dmetrics.reporter.flink_prometheus_ops_reporter.class=org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter \
    -Dmetrics.reporter.flink_prometheus_ops_reporter.port=9150-9200
```

The batch flink job code attach here:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setParallelism(128);
        List<DataSet<String>> sources = new ArrayList<DataSet<String>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
             DataSet<String> inhouseDateSet = env.readTextFile("hdfs://namenode/path" + i);
             sources.add(inhouseDateSet);
        }
        DataSet<String> dataSet = sources.get(0);
        for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++){
             dataSet = dataSet.union(sources.get(i));
        }

        GroupReduceOperator<User, User> userResult = dataSet
                .flatMap(new EventMapOperator())
                .groupBy(1)
                .reduceGroup(new SelfGroupReducer());

        userResult.map(User::toString).writeAsText("hdfs://namenode/out_path");
        env.execute();
    }
```

However, the job always throw Exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Heartbeat of TaskManager with id container_e05_1578886899625_23144_01_000159 timed out.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster$TaskManagerHeartbeatListener.notifyHeartbeatTimeout(JobMaster.java:1149)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.heartbeat.HeartbeatMonitorImpl.run(HeartbeatMonitorImpl.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRunAsync(AkkaRpcActor.java:397)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:190)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:152)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Or throw this Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Update to task [CHAIN FlatMap (FlatMap at main(RcmdPerformanceETLBatchJob.java:35)) -> Map (Key Extractor) (111/128) - execution #4] on TaskManager container_e05_1578886899625_18703_01_000094 @ hadoop-data-234.recommend.shopeemobile.com (dataPort=34531) failed
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.lambda$sendUpdatePartitionInfoRpcCall$14(Execution.java:1395)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:442)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRunAsync(AkkaRpcActor.java:397)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:190)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:152)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka.tcp://flink@hadoop-data-234.recommend.shopeemobile.com:29851/user/taskmanager_0#1997707422]] after [10000 ms]. Message of type [org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.messages.RemoteRpcInvocation]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:871)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:263)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:261)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:191)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:188)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:74)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:644)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:205)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:328)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:279)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:283)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka.tcp://flink@hadoop-data-234.recommend.shopeemobile.com:29851/user/taskmanager_0#1997707422]] after [10000 ms]. Message of type [org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.messages.RemoteRpcInvocation]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$2.apply(AskSupport.scala:635)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$2.apply(AskSupport.scala:635)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:648)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Am I reading this correctly, that you have parallelism of 128, and each instance is reading the same 100 files?

Comment: I don't think you are correct,  this job have parallelism of 128,  there are 100 path need to involve as source, and union them to one dataset

Comment: I believe each of the 128 instances will open all 100 files, read a slice, and union those slices together. Question is, how will hdfs perform under this load.

Comment: I see, but I haven't seen any error about HDFS so far

Comment: Hi @alvin any update no this error. were you able to debug or finally resolved it?

Comment: Hi @Piyush_Rana , I just decrease the parallelism and give more memory resource for this job, it works but sometimes it still fails

Comment: @Piyush_Rana the root cause is memory is not enough and GC STW time is so long which is greater than akka timeout. I just increase memory and akka timeout, it resolve.